# Handling a Promise reject in axios interceptor

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, axios

Having trouble dealing with a specific case of an error, seems like my understanding of promises is flawed.
Central error handling in axios interceptor, handles all my calls to the api and most of my errors, it looks like this:

```
export function apiFactory(vue, $security) {
  const $http = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.API_URL
  });

  $http.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    const token = $security.loginFrame.getToken();

    if (token) {
      config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
    }

    return config;

  }, function (err) {
    vue.$eventBus.$emit('toastMessageHandler', {message: error.message, type: 'error'});
    return Promise.reject(err);
  });

  $http.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {

    return response;

  }, function (error) {
    if (error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
      vue.$eventBus.$emit('authErr', error);
    } else if (error.response && error.response.status === 403) {
      alert('you are not authorized, please contact EM support');
    }
    else if (error.response && error.response.status !== 409){
      vue.$eventBus.$emit('toastMessageHandler', {message: error.message, type: 'error'});
    }

    return Promise.reject(error);
  });
```

This works well for most cases but in one case, where I make this api call:

```
async createSearchTerm(term) {
      return await this.$http({
        url: `/v1/searchTerms/term`,
        method: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(term)
      })
  }
```

The `409` error which I am trying to catch does not reach the component, my code in the component looks like this:

```
 async addTag() {  //needs better error handling, make sure loader changes in cases of fail.
        if (this.newTag.length > 0) {
          this.loading = true
          this.$emit('loading', true)
          const payload = {
            term: this.newTag,
            term_type: this.type,
            partner_code: this.query.partner_code,
            language: this.query.language
          }
          try {
            await this.apiFacade.createSearchTerm(payload); //this is the call directly above, it just goes through a facade.
            this.$emit('loading', false)
            this.loading = false
            this.tags.unshift(this.newTag)
            this.newTag = ''
            this.$eventBus.$emit('toastMessageHandler', {
              message: this.$t(`search_terms.add_success`),
              type: 'info'
            });
          } catch (e) { //error is undefined
            if (e.response.status === 409) {
              this.$eventBus.$emit('toastMessageHandler', {
                message: this.$t(`search_terms.duplicate_term`),
                type: 'error'
              });
            }
          }
        }
      },
```

It seems as though my Interceptor returns a promise and not an object therefore I cannot handle it. Ideally I wouldn't need to resolve the promise in the components rather it would just receive the error message. What is the recommended way to pass to my component the actual error so I can properly handle it?

**Expected** - pass the `error` object to the location where the call the fails.
**actual** - `error` is undefined.

**EDIT** I was able to see the error and handle it when I changed the code in 2 places, in the interceptor code: 
`return Promise.reject({error});`
And then in the component:
`catch ({error}) { //error is undefined
            if (error.response.status === 409)`
I do not actually understand why this is the case? possibly because destructuring forces the promise to resolve?

Comment: I have something very similar set up and it works fine, I know that's not helpful, but when I debug it, it says that `e` is`undefined` too but it's actually not, can you `console.log` it out to see if it is actually `undefined`. Also is it not `e.response.status` instead of `status` in your catch

Comment: I tried your suggestion unfortunately no go. I did add it into the code since it is correct.

Comment: Do you see the request/response in the network tab? Apologies for all the questions, your code _seems_ fine, so it could be happening elsewhere.

Comment: Yes I get a 409 in the network tab, it's definitely there just not reaching the error handler in the component.

Comment: Try ```throw error;``` instead of ```return Promise.reject(error);``` in the interceptor.

Comment: Tried that, it seems that's just a serialized error not really better

Comment: Are you using CORS? If you are and the server isn't setting all the right headers then you'll have very limited access to the resulting error. I wouldn't expect `error` to be `undefined` but `error.response` would be.

Comment: @skirtle the header is set correctly otherwise I would not be getting a response and be able to communicate with the server, the issue is with handling a specific error which is passed to a component.

Comment: @butchyyyy saved my life! Exactly what I was looking for.